# Django sending Email confusion

Tags: python, django, email, django-views

I've used one application with sending email to the user for notification. but in that application setting.py file contains some confusing terms like
in

> setting file

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I'm not sure what this is and also

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'rquest186@gmail.com'
```

what is the variety in this two

and if host is declared here then

> mail.py

```
def send_mail(title,message,reciver):
    try:
        mailS = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        mailP = 587
        mailUsr = "idefusiontest2015@gmail.com" 
        mailPass = "********"

        # Create a text/plain message
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

        msg['Subject'] = title
        msg['From'] = mailUsr
        msg['To'] = reciver

        html="<html><head></head><body><p>"+message.replace("\n","<br>")+"</p></body></html>"

        part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

        msg.attach(part2)

        # Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
        s = smtplib.SMTP(mailS,mailP)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()
        s.login(mailUsr,mailPass)
        s.sendmail(mailUsr, [reciver], msg.as_string())
        s.quit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

in this

```
 mailUsr = "idefusiontest2015@gmail.com" ???? what's this for ?
```

I'm new to this. and it's confusing for me.
thanks in adv.

Comment: Maybe you should take a few minutes to read Django documentation page related to email: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a gmail account to send mail from:

```
mailUsr = "idefusiontest2015@gmail.com" 
mailPass = "IDEF2017"
```

`MailUsr` is the emailid and `MailPass` is passowrd of that account.

It is like for sending mail you are logging to `gmail` account using these emailid and password and then sending the mail.

So if you want to send then you need to use your emailid and password in place of that.

> settings.py

You need to have these settings.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

- `EMAIL_HOST` is the `smtp` service you are using. In my case it is `sendgrid` in your case `gmail`.
- `EMAIL_HOST_USER` is the username from that `smtp` service in your case your `gmailid` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` password for that account.

I think it should be clear to you by now.

Comment: what about
** EMAIL_USE_TLS = True**

Comment: It is port for sending secure mails. TLS(Transport Layer Security Protocol).

Comment: If you use `port:25` it is not secure. It is like accessing `https` on port 443 and `http` on port 80

Comment: If my answer made your understanding clear, you can upvote and select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The the values from settings.py file will be automatically used while sending mail when if you are using django mail sending package like EmailMessage() for SendMail [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/)

the second one that you are using is native python package . on that you have to explicitly provide the username and password and other configurations

sorry about the language .. :)